# when clicking on calender next button it showing the whole page in the div

Tags: php, ajax

This is the `ajax request` to load next and previous page

```
$sCalendarItself = strtr(file_get_contents('templates/calendar.php'), $aKeys);

    // AJAX requests - return the calendar
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
              && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' 
              && isset($_GET['month'])) 
    {
                header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                echo $sCalendarItself;
                exit;
    }

    $aVariables = array(
            '__calendar__' => $sCalendarItself,
    );
        echo strtr(file_get_contents('templates/index.php'), $aVariables);
?>
```

and this is my `calendar.php` in template folder

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a class="prev" href="#calendar?month=__prev_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('foodcalendar.php?month=__prev_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;"></a>
    <div class="title" >__cal_caption__</div>
    <a class="next" href="#calendar?month=__next_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('foodcalendar.php?month=__next_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;"></a>
</div>
```

and this is index.php in templates folder

```
<div id="calendar">
    __calendar__
</div>
```

and when i click on the next month link it is loading the next month calendar with the whole page html element. I just want to load that calendar div and show only the next month calendar in that particular div